# Can non type template arguments done on stl containers?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, containers, std

```
template<typename T,int nSize>
T Sum(T (&parr)[nSize])
{
    T sum=0;
    for(int i = 0; i < nSize ;++i)
    {
        sum += parr[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int nArr[] = {1,2,3,4};
    int nSum = Sum(nArr);
   std::cout<<"Sum :"<<nSum;
}
```

Can `std::vector` be used instead of *array*.Or can *array* be replaced by any of the stl containers?

Comment: No. Take in two templated iterators instead of an array and your function will work with virtually any container out there.

Comment: how can it be done using two templated iterators.can you elaborate?

Comment: @MohammedAliJahfer, use a range for your function. One template parameter for type T and another for Input iterator

Comment: @kuro so we cannot done using  non type template argument.Right?

Answer (score 4):

> Can `std::vector` be used instead of *array*.Or can *array* be replaced by
>   any of the stl containers?

No. It is not possible as they are different in their types. But you can generalize the given function in the following way.

Make a template function taking the begin and end iterators of the container. Then using [`std::accumulate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate), sum the elements up, which will work for *[any sequence containers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container#Sequence_containers)* as well as the arrays:

Following is an example code: **([See live online](https://wandbox.org/permlink/0cnd92nsyDpihm8M))**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <numeric>  // std::accumulate
#include <iterator> // std::iterator_traits, std::cbegin, std::cend

template<typename Iterator>
constexpr auto Sum(Iterator begin, const Iterator end) -> typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type
{
    using RetType = typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type;
    return std::accumulate(begin, end, RetType{});
}

int main()
{
    int nArr[] = { 1,2,3,4 };
    std::vector<int> vec{ 1,2,3,4 };
    std::list<int> list{ 1,2,3,4 };
    // now you can
    std::cout << "Sum of array: " << Sum(std::cbegin(nArr), std::cend(nArr)) << "\n";
    std::cout << "Sum of vec: "   << Sum(std::cbegin(vec), std::cend(vec)) << "\n";
    std::cout << "Sum of list: "  << Sum(std::cbegin(list), std::cend(list)) << "\n";
}
```

**Output**:

```
Sum of array: 10
Sum of vec: 10
Sum of list: 10
```

Answer (score 2):

```
template<typename T, int nSize>
T sum(std::array<T, nSize> const&);
```

would be the equivalent signature for `std::array`. As you see, signature differs already. Trying to do the same for `std::vector` is bound to fail:

```
template<typename T, int nSize>
T sum(std::vector<T> const&);
```

How would you be able to know at *compile time* already how many elements will reside in the vector??? You simply cannot. Even if you specified `nSize` in code explicitly, e. g. `sum<std::vector<int>, 7>`, the function then would *always* try to iterate over exactly seven elements, resulting in undefined behaviour if there are less and not counting the surplus ones if there are more...

The typical way to go is using begin and end iterators, just as the standard library does, too, for all of its algorithms:

```
template <typename Iterator>
auto sum(Iterator begin, Iterator end) -> std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*begin)>
{
    using type = decltype(sum(begin, end)); // just not wanting to repeat all
                                            // that remove_reference stuff...
    type s = type();
    for( ; begin != end; ++begin)
    {
        s += *begin;
    }
    return s;
}
```

You additionally could, based on this function, provide a generic overload for arbitrary containers then:

```
template <typename Container>
auto sum(Container const& c)
{
    using std::begin;
    using std::end;
    return sum(begin(c), end(c));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your compiler supports C++ 17 then you can write a single function with using `if constexpr` statement.

For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
auto Sum( const T &container )
{
    if constexpr( std::is_array_v<std::remove_reference_t<T>> )
    {
        std::remove_extent_t<T> sum = 0;
        for ( const auto &item : container )
        {
            sum += item;
        }

        return sum;
    }
    else
    {
        typename T::value_type sum = 0;
        for ( const auto &item : container )
        {
            sum += item;
        }

        return sum;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int nArr[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    int nSum = Sum( nArr );
    std::cout << "Sum :"<<nSum << '\n';;

    std::vector<int> v = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    nSum = Sum( v );
    std::cout << "Sum :"<<nSum << '\n';;
}
```

The program output is

```
Sum :10
Sum :10
```

However it is better to split the function into two functions: one for arrays and other for standard containers.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<typename T, size_t N>
auto Sum( const T ( &a )[N] )
{
    T sum = 0;

    for ( const auto &item : a )
    {
        sum += item;
    }

    return sum;
}

template<typename T>
auto Sum( const T &container )
{
    typename T::value_type sum = 0;
    for ( const auto &item : container )
    {
        sum += item;
    }

    return sum;
}

int main()
{
    int nArr[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    int nSum = Sum( nArr );
    std::cout << "Sum :"<<nSum << '\n';;

    std::vector<int> v = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    nSum = Sum( v );
    std::cout << "Sum :"<<nSum << '\n';;
}
```

Comment: Possibly something like `std::decay_t<decltype(*std::begin(container))> Sum{};` for common code.

Comment: @Aconcagua For iterators there is the standard algorithm std::accumulate. You can call it within the template functions instead of the loop.

Comment: Haha, having been too slow dropping my comment... Actually, I considered calculating a sum just as an example for creating a mre and real code might do something entirely different – too much of interpretation?